# Swift MPMediaPropertyPredicate not filtering for selected albums songs

Tags: ios, swift

I am on my second rewrite on a media player.  The first one was in Objective C and worked great.   The second one I built in swift mainly to make a more efficient music player and to get up to speed in the new language.

In my media picker I'm trying to get the album songs after I've tapped on an album.  I can filter by Artists, but when I apply the Album filter, I get an empty table.  Here is the code:

```
// Get the representative media item
var itemCollection: MPMediaItemCollection =
    items!.objectAtIndex(itemRow) as MPMediaItemCollection

var mediaItem: MPMediaItem = itemCollection.representativeItem

//Build the query with predicate filters
var albumPredicate: MPMediaPropertyPredicate =
    MPMediaPropertyPredicate(value: mediaItem.albumTitle,
                       forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle)

var artistPredicate: MPMediaPropertyPredicate =
    MPMediaPropertyPredicate(value: mediaItem.artist,
                       forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumArtist)

var noCloudPredicate: MPMediaPropertyPredicate =
    MPMediaPropertyPredicate(value: NSNumber.numberWithBool(false),
                       forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyIsCloudItem)

var query: MPMediaQuery = MPMediaQuery.songsQuery()
query.addFilterPredicate(noCloudPredicate)
query.addFilterPredicate(artistPredicate)
query.addFilterPredicate(albumPredicate)
```

If I comment out the `albumPredicate`, I will get a correct listing of all songs under the selected artist which means my storyboard is wired correctly. Also, `mediaItem.albumTitle` returns the selected album title correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it! Seems I was focusing in the wrong area.  I had bad code in the `override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int)` that returned 0 when I only had one section thus no rows shown when filtering by album. Doh!

Answer (score 1):

Tommy thanks for your reply. I have used multiple filterPredicates in a single query and it works in Objective C. All of the following code works on the objective c music player but the equivalent swift albumPredicate does not work:

```
MPMediaItemCollection *itemCollection = [[self items] objectAtIndex:itemIndex];
MPMediaItem *mediaItem = [itemCollection representativeItem];

MPMediaPropertyPredicate *albumPredicate =
    [MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:[mediaItem albumTitle]
                                     forProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle];

MPMediaPropertyPredicate *artistPredicate =
    [MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:[mediaItem artist]
                                     forProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumArtist];
MPMediaPropertyPredicate *noCloudPredicate =
    [MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]
                                     forProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyIsCloudItem];

MPMediaQuery *query = [MPMediaQuery songsQuery];
[query addFilterPredicate:noCloudPredicate];
[query addFilterPredicate:artistPredicate];
[query addFilterPredicate:albumPredicate];
```

My understanding is the `[MPMediaQuery songsQuery]` will select songs and group by songs. Then the predicates are applied. I would like to know why it doesn't work in swift.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can compound an album and an artist predicate.  I had to write a query which returned all songs for an artist and then ripped through them and filtered the albums manually.

Here is my code which does this.

```
class func getArtistSongsWithoutSettingPlaylist(currentSong : MPMediaItem?) -> ([[MPMediaItem]], [MPMediaItem]) {
    //album->*song
    var songs = [MPMediaItem]()
    var groupedSongs = [[MPMediaItem]]()
    if currentSong != nil {
        var query = MPMediaQuery.songsQuery()
        var pred = MPMediaPropertyPredicate(value: currentSong!.albumArtist, forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumArtist)
        query.addFilterPredicate(pred)
        var artistSongs = query.items as [MPMediaItem]
        var albumDic = Dictionary<String,Array<MPMediaItem>>(minimumCapacity: artistSongs.count)
        //fill up the dictionary with songs
        for x in artistSongs {
            if albumDic.indexForKey(x.albumTitle) == nil {
                albumDic[x.albumTitle] = Array<MPMediaItem>()
            }
            albumDic[x.albumTitle]?.append(x)
        }

        //get them back out by album and insert into array of arrays
        for (x,y) in albumDic {
            var sorted = y.sorted { $0.albumTrackNumber < $1.albumTrackNumber }
            groupedSongs.append(sorted)
        }
        //now sort the grouped playlist by year
        groupedSongs.sort { $0[0].year > $1[0].year }
        //now add all the groupplaylist into one big playlist for the media player
        for album in groupedSongs {
            songs.extend(album)
        }
        outputSongs(songs)
    }
    return (groupedSongs, songs)
}
```